# Compare two values

Tags: vbscript

I want to compare two values which is coming as string input. please help me how to compare this values

```
strA = "25.03"
strB = "-25.02"
```

Raja

Answer (score 5):

```
Cdbl(strA) < Cdbl(strB)
```

will cast them to double

Answer (score 3):

It might help to know what kind of validation you want to do.

String?

```
strA = "25.03"
strB = "-25.02"
If strA > strB Then
   'do whatever'
End If
```

Numeric reguardless of sign?

```
strA = "25.03"
strB = "-25.02"
If Abs(strA) > Abs(strB) Then
   'do whatever'
End If
```

Numeric including the decimal?

```
strA = "25.03"
strB = "-25.02"
If cDbl(strA) > cDbl(strB) Then
   'do whatever'
End If
```

Numeric excluding the decimal?

```
strA = "25.03"
strB = "-25.02"
If cInt(strA) > cInt(strB) Then
   'do whatever'
End If
```

More information and context would go a long way in getting you the answer you need...

Answer (score 0):

You can convert them to values with the val function, and then you can make any comparation

```
valA = Val(strA)
valB = Val(strB)

If valA > valB Then
  ' Do whatever you need
End If
```

Comment: VBScript doesn't have the `Val` function.